# sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting

Tags: command-line

I cannot use sudo. When I type `sudo -i` in the terminal to switch to the root user, the following error is displayed:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Can you help me?